# HWUT: how to enlarge the maximal size of a test result file?

Tags: c, unit-testing

in HWUT (hello world unit test), how can I change the maximal size of a test output file. Currently it seems to be limited to 1kB.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The default limit is 1MB which is reasonable**. You can adapt the maximum 
output file size by means of the environment variable

```
            HWUT_OUTPUT_FILE_MAX_SIZE
```

**But be careful!** The size limit exists to prevent the test application 
from spamming you hard drive with nonsense data. ***A loopy freaked-out test 
application may very well stall your computer if it flushes so badly that no more space for others remains.***

Also, while HWUT can be very flexible during output comparison, I doubt
that more than 1MB of content can be judged appropriately. Maybe, filtering
the output would make sense.